# Unlock the Android Lockscreen

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I unlock the screen programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959012/how-can-i-unlock-the-screen-programmatically-in-android)

I have a running android Service. It runs even on the lockscreen, and I want it to somehow Unlock the lockscreen.

How can I interface with the lockscreen activity or whatever the lockscreen is?

I want my service to Unlock the lockscreen, just like if the user slided the unlock thing.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

got it and here are some suggestions you can try:

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959012/how-can-i-unlock-the-screen-programmatically-in-android)

[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/android-how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically)

[Third and probably most reliable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/activity_testing.html#UnlockDevice)

Comment: Yeah, i already saw those topics... The Keyguard only works to lock or unlock the KEYS. It doesn't allow me to interact with the lockscreen

Comment: and how exactly do you want to interact with the unlock screen? the same way the user touches. you want to be able to slide it? thats not possible. this is all you get. sorry.

Comment: I don't want to "slide it" programmatically, but i want to send an "unlock" event programmatically... The same event that is thrown when the user slides it! =]

Comment: Well thats also not possible as far as i know. i sure hope that somebody will prove me wrong on this one.