# Is there any way to unlock a phone's screen during testing? 

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, adb

I'm working on writing a test to be added to an automated test script, and I want to be able to guarantee that the phone's screen is on as part of my initialization process. I have no real preference as to how to accomplish this, so I'm fine with either ADB or Java, or whatever method might be applicable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I unlock the screen programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959012/how-can-i-unlock-the-screen-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Have you seen this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959012/how-can-i-unlock-the-screen-programmatically-in-android)

The answers give solutions using both code in the onCreate method or adb.