# What's the non-deprecated way of turning a screen on programmatically on Android

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

Googling and checking SO answers gives me many working options on how to turn the screen on for Android, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891337/turning-on-screen-programmatically). But all of them uses one or more deprecated methods or enums. If I try the replacements, they don't work. My goal is to do this at the start of instrumentation tests without using deprecated methods.

Here are my attempts

A)

```
val power = context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
val wakeLock = power.newWakeLock(FULL_WAKE_LOCK or ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP or ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "tag")
wakeLock.acquire()
```

Works, but uses deprecated enum `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`. Removing that flag causes an error telling me to specify a level. The deprecation doc says I should rather use `android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` instead. So I try that in B:

B) 
In `onCreate`:

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

This did not turn the screen on.

C)

I also noticed there are a couple of interesting flags for the activity to set in the manifest. I tried:

```
android:turnScreenOn="true"
android:showWhenLocked="true"
```

This did not turn the screen on

While solution A works, I strive to use non-deprecated functions. This is more of an academic question. Does anyone know how to programatically turn the screen on while not using deprecated functions or constants?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Espresso, Wake up device before test. How to use a custom manifest for test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870771/android-espresso-wake-up-device-before-test-how-to-use-a-custom-manifest-for-t)

Comment: No, the answer uses the depreacted constant `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`